# How to make intertools arima grid-search run faster

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools, grid-search

I have an ARIMA grid-search function with `intertools` that I trust to give me the best ARIMA model of a `time-series` data of 400 datasets but it has been running 72 hours actually producing results but too slow. How can I make it very very fast to run in a few minutes?

I have tried `d=0, p=q=range(0,3)` insted of `p = d = q = range(0, 3)` which gave me error.

```
# Generate the `ts` data 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range('1985-01', periods=400, freq='M')
ts = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
ts['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
ts.head(5)
```

.

```
import warnings
import itertools
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # specify to ignore warning messages

# Define the p, d and q parameters to take any value between 0 and 2
p = d = q = range(0, 3)

# Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))

# Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

print('Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...')
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[1]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[2]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[3]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[4]))
```

.

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # specify to ignore warning messages

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(ts,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```

I want to make the python code very very fast in minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's me again. So, I try to find another faster way and maybe the solution could be use multiprocessing. I try it today but I found some little problems that a I [post it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066091/processpoolexecutor-dont-execute/65066142#65066142) to somebody can help us.

BTW. Meanwhile searching, I found another faster way, so if you are interested you can us this code

```py
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

series = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', header=None, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
train, test = series[1:900], series[900:]


Arima_model=auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1, max_p=8, max_q=8, start_P=0, start_Q=0, max_P=8, max_Q=8, m=12, seasonal=True, trace=True, d=1, D=1, error_action='warn', suppress_warnings=True, random_state = 20, n_fits=30)
```