# ProcessPoolExecutor don't Execute

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arima

I try to get ARIMA configuration some faster that I acctually do.

So I use a Iterate method to compare all ARIMA combinations to select better. For that I create a function to Iterate:

```py
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
        diff.append(value)
    return np.array(diff)

# invert differenced value
def inverse_difference(history, yhat, interval=1):
    return yhat + history[-interval]

# evaluate an ARIMA model for a given order (p,d,q) and return RMSE
def evaluate_arima_model(dataset, arima_order):

    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.50)
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:]
    
    history = [x for x in train]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test)):
        # difference data
        months_in_year = maxlength
        diff = difference(history, months_in_year)
        model = ARIMA(diff, order=arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        yhat = inverse_difference(history, yhat, months_in_year)
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test[t])
    # calculate out of sample error
    mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
    rmse = sqrt(mse)
    return rmse
```

Actually I do that in minutes with this method. But isn't good time for an API where I gonna use the logic.

```py
# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model

def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.50)
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:]
    
    global best_score, best_cfg 
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                try:
                    mse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order)
                    if mse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = mse, order
                    print('ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (order,mse))
                except:
                    continue
        # print(best_cfg, best_score)
    print('Best ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))




# evaluate parameters
p_values = range(0, 7)
d_values = range(0, 3)
q_values = range(0, 7)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
evaluate_models(data_train.values, p_values, d_values, q_values)
```

To acelerate the process I want use Multiprocessing method  iterating `evaluate_arima_model` function. But *ProcessPoolExecutor* don't work because don't print any result

```py
# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
orders = []
def fill_orders( p_values, d_values, q_values):
    
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                orders.append(order)

# fill orders array
p_values = range(0, 7)
d_values = range(0, 3)
q_values = range(0, 7)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
fill_orders(p_values, d_values, q_values)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(evaluate_arima_model, (dataset, order)) for order in orders]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())
        try:
            f.result()
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print(f.result())
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the second block of code you've shown to do anything.  For this code:

```
# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
orders = []
def evaluate_models( p_values, d_values, q_values):
    
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                orders.append(order)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(evaluate_arima_model, (dataset, order)) for order in orders]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())
        try:
            f.result()
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print(f.result())
```

`orders` will always be empty because you are declaring it so and then never calling `evaluate_models`, or anything else that could be putting objects into `orders`.  Since `orders` is empty, no processes will be registered to run, and `results` will also be empty, and so this code won't do anything.  Do you mean to call `evaluate_models` before you do `with concurrent.futures....`?

Comment: Ok, I understand the poit but I really execute the functions to create or fill `orders`, just I forgot change the function name, but Yes of course execute. I'll edit the document